# How to create image upload API using asp dotnet form webservice to connect database

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

```
[WebMethod]
public void ImageUplod(string image, string name, string email, string mobile, string Password)
{


        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);

         string fileExtension = ".png";

        string fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{fileExtension}";

        string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload/");

        string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes);

        DataClasses1DataContext dd = new DataClasses1DataContext(strcon);
        var ll = dd.Demo_register_sp(fileName, name, email, mobile, Password).ToString();
        JavaScriptSerializer jj = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(jj.Serialize(ll));
    }
```

I want to send file in file format not base64 format using post method please help...

Comment: You have to make it a MIME attachment if you do not encode to Base64.  A MIME attachment in a body of HTTP starts with two dashes on a new line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  The library you are using should have a method to add an attachment.   The library method is not shown in your posted code.

Comment: Do you REALLY want to write your own up-loader? There are boatloads of fantastic up-loaders. Most don't do a page post-back, most allow a hot zone drag and drop area. And most are "chunked" which allows files of any size. Grab the one from the free ajaxtoolkit, or even say https://pqina.nl/filepond/   -- really, I would not try to roll my own when such fantastic, free and "battle" hardened example up-loaders can be had for free.